# Constraint conflict error for unexisting constraint xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, constraints

I'm quite new in ios development, so maybe it's a silly question.

[image]

## Error

[image]

The constraint that I'm trying to apply is the one for the Circle Slider (Circle Slider.leading = leading + 16) but when I create it xcode give me an error (see second image) telling me that exist another constraint in conflict whit the one I'm trying to apply. As you can see the "leading = CircleSlider.leading" constraint doesn't exist! Also if I go to size inspector there isn't! I've also tryed to clean constraint for the circle slider but without success.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added Circle Slider in StackView. StackView uses it's own constraints to arrange views inside it. So, second hidden constraint you are talking is given by Xcode it self. 
When you gives constraint leading + 15 which conflicts with leading (leading + 0).
So here, you have to remove constraint you given manually.

Comment: Ohh got it, I've fixed editing layout margin on stackview. Thanks a lot!